# Is the outlined plan to add a crawlspace GFCI and light reasonable/correct?

Tags: wiring, gfci, circuit

**goal**: I want to add a 20A GFCI and light to my crawlspace fed from an existing 20A circuit.

**existing**: I have a 20A GFCI receptacle (kitchen) supplied by a 12-2 straight run (via the crawl space) from the panel (20A breaker). Off the load side of the GFCI receptacle is another 20A kitchen receptacle.

**proposed**: In the crawlspace I want to branch off the straight run to the GFCI (above) to a new 20A GFCI receptacle in the crawlspace and off the load side run a switch to a fixed light.

**question**: Are there any problems with this plan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the circuit serves kitchen receptacles, it cannot serve any other load, except for a wall clock or gas range in that same kitchen.

You will need to choose another circuit to tap.

Unfortunately you will have the same problem with bathroom or laundry room receptacle circuits. Those are out of bounds too.

Answer (score 2):

Fine plan; the only issue might be finding about a foot of slack to support your new junction box. If you don't have slack, you can set the junction box near where the kitchen outlet drops and re-fish 12-2 to the kitchen outlet. Or you can put two boxes near each other with a new piece of 12-2 between.

You can probably save a few bucks by using a regular 15A outlet in the crawlspace... it's one of the rare exceptions to the idea that everything on a 20A circuit has to be able to withstand 20A of current. (National Electrical Code, article 210.21 (B) 1, 2, and 3.) Whatever you do, don't hook the outgoing wire to the load terminals of the crawlspace gfci.

You probably know this already, but I'll note that all the new wiring has to be AWG12.

Edit to say that @Harper is right about the technical restrictions on borrowing from kitchen circuits. I'll leave my answer otherwise intact in case it helps similar situations.

Comment: I feel funny putting a 15A switch on a 20A line. I know it's allowed, but I don't understand it!